# bcrypt nodejs - null error when trying to login with comparing hashed password from the database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, routes, bcrypt

I created a basic register and login page connected to local mysql - that collects email, username and password (password gets hashed with bcrypt) and stores them in database.

Yet when i am trying to log in I get an error that says just : **null** + (console log saying **password + else2** so i know which line got called)

**This is login.js file**

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let username = req.body.username;
    

//if it finds username and email matching login credentials it will check for password
    db.query('SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND email = ?', [username, email], function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                "code": 400,
                "failed": "error ocurred"
            });
        }


//results[0].password means the password of the user that was found.

// it should compare plain password with the encrypted password in database
//and redirect to the /profile page if the password are a match.

        if (results.length > 0) {
            
            bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function (error, answer) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(password +'if1')
                    console.log("comparing gone wrong", error);
                    return res.render('login', {
                        message3: 'Comparing error - please try again later'
                    });
                }

                if (answer) {
                    console.log(password + 'if 2')
                    res.redirect("/profile");
                    console.log("login successfull!");
                } 
                
                else {
                    console.log(password + ' else2', error)
                    return res.render('login', {
                        message3: 'User or password or email is wrong'
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(password + 'else3')
            return res.render('login', {
                message3: 'User or password or email is wrong'
                
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**I will also put the register.js file if that will help with anything.**

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const { username, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        if( result.length > 0 ) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That email is already in use'
            })
        } else if( password !== passwordConfirm) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That passwords do not match'
            });
        }

        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        console.log(hashedPassword);

        db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {username: username, email: email, password: hashedPassword }, (error, result) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);

            }   else {
                console.log(result);
                return res.render('register', {
                    message2: 'User Registered!'
                });

            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: First, find which `console.log` prints `null`

Comment: `error` is `null` if there is no error

Comment: @Konrad it's first else statement - in login.js file - that prints null

" else {
                    console.log(password + ' else2', error)
                    return res.render('login', {
                        message3: 'User or password or email is wrong'
                    });"

i also get content of message 3 on the page as an alert, so i am sure it's this one that happens

Comment: Is the `results[0].password` return correct ?

Comment: @hungtran273 it is, I now added console log for (password, results[0].password) which is
(password type by user, hashed pasword stored in the database).

And it returns correctly the same hash from the database for password banan.
 banan $2a$08$VPNWJFkGxDfJA7mvjLA67emOsOWCXYj6/vMGQNjFrK1

Comment: This site https://bcrypt-generator.com/ says that those two don't match

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I know why finding an answer online was so hard.

The code is right, the problem was in my database, I previously allowed for 50 Varchar password (but hashing it makes it longer, and it was getting cut), after I changed it to 128 chars it works perfectly with the new users that now register and login under the new broader restrictions.